# How Do I bind a button Content with a list of numbers in WP8?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-phone-8

At first let me tell you, what I want to achieve. I want that when a windows page loads it will create a lot of buttons, say 10 buttons now at run time I want this `Button.Content` to Bind with some listvalues, which is a list of 10 numbers.

`public List<int> listvalues = new list<int>();`

I want to do this in MVVM, so my approach is in model I have `public int ListNumbers`  property, with `OnPropertyChanged` event is defined. Now in the view Model, how do I fill a list `listvalues` with some 10 integer values(Exactly new to MVVM that's why I am asking). This Ten values will be used for the Content of the 10 Buttons that are run time generated. And after filling the `listvalues`in the `MainPage_Loaded` Method of the MainPage how do bind the Content of the Button with the `listvalues` .

To better understand my requirement...

I have below XAMl code

`<Canvas x:Name="GameCanvas" Background="Bisque" Height="480" Width="480" />` in `MainPage.xaml`

So in the code behind

```
int locationFirst = 25;
int locationSecond = 100;

char SeatValue = 'A';

int row = 3;
int column = 3;

    public GamePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int x = 1; x <= row; x++)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= column; i++)
            {
                CreateButtons(SeatValue.ToString() + i, locationFirst, locationSecond);
                locationFirst = locationFirst + 130;
            }
            locationFirst = 25;
            locationSecond = locationSecond + 50;
        }

    }
```

The createButtons code is

```
Button btnNew = new Button();
btnNew.Name = btnName;
btnNew.Margin = new Thickness(btnPointFirst, btnPointSecond, 0, 0);
btnNew.Width = 100;
btnNew.Height = 70;
GameCanvas.Children.Add(btnNew);
```

In the Windows Phone I found an issue, is that there is no btnNew.Location(X,Y);

So at run time I have to use 
`btnNew.Margin = new Thickness(btnPointFirst, btnPointSecond, 0, 0);` 
which is not putting the buttons in the desired location. However this is my code now how do I assign btnNew.Content with the `listNumbers` value?

Please help.

Any link or any elaborate answer is fine for me...

Thanks

Comment: can you share some more code e.g how are you generating the buttons?

Comment: You're English is hard to understand... what is this `ListNumbers` property and what is it for? What do you mean by 'fill a list with some 10 integer values'? What list? A new list? Do you just want to add the text (`Content`) to the `Button` objects?

Comment: Sorry for the English, ListNumbers is a collections of List<int>(); this ListNumbers  I will fill in the ViewModel Class. Yes I want this populated ListNumbers values to be the Content of the Button. 
Say `btn1.Content = listNumbers[i]; ` `btn2.Content = listNumbers[i+1];` and it will be in the for loop. Hope now I am clear, if not feel free to ask me.

Comment: In MVVM you will not use the MainPage_Loaded, in fact, you're not gonna use any method of the code-behind file (except for view-specific stuff)

Comment: @nit I have added my code...

Comment: @EduardoBrites then any idea how do i fire the Loaded Event using viewModel?

Comment: Can you post your ViewModel?

Comment: Are you creating the buttons dynamically or they are all defined in your .xaml page?

Comment: @LeoLorenzoLuis I am creating the buttons dynamically, the code is given `CreateButtons` code... regarding ViewModel I am not clear of what to be inside VieModel, but I want in my viewModel, there will be a List of Numbers of integers and from the Integers List, 10 numbers will be the content of the Buttons. Hope you understood.

Comment: @Debhere You will not need the load event. The bindings to the viewmodel's properties are enough. I suggest you learn more about MVVM  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Comment: @EduardoBrites Thanks, I will definitely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood this one

```
public GamePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = GamePageViewModel();
    for (int x = 1; x <= row; x++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= column; i++)
        {
            CreateButtons(SeatValue.ToString() + i, locationFirst, locationSecond);
            locationFirst = locationFirst + 130;
        }
        locationFirst = 25;
        locationSecond = locationSecond + 50;
    }

}

public class GamePageViewModel
{
   //List of numbers to put e.g. List<int>
   //Change PropertyNameOfTheViewModel here to properties, say 10 properties e.g, public int Content { get; set; }
} 

Button btnNew = new Button();
btnNew.Name = btnName;
btnNew.Margin = new Thickness(btnPointFirst, btnPointSecond, 0, 0);
btnNew.Width = 100;
btnNew.Height = 70;
btnNew.SetBinding(Button.ContentProperty,new Binding("PropertyNameOfTheViewModel");
```

But then, I wouldn't recommend doing this kind of stuff in the ViewModel because it is unnecessary, you only use the binding to a ViewModel if the one you are planning to show in the UI is coming from a database/business logic. Setting button contents from 1-10 is not gonna be in the ViewModel, if you continue you'll end up with unnecessary code in the ViewModel thus breaking the MVVM pattern.

My question is, why do you have to do this with binding? Just set the Button Content when you are creating it in the MainPage.xaml.cs, that is correct. You are just adding unnecessary layer just to set the button's content.